# Google Analytics in Wordpress - Cross-Domain Tracking

Tags: wordpress, onclick, google-analytics, cross-domain

I've searched high and low for an answer for this problem and need the help of experts.

The website I'm helping to oversee has a registration in a frame on their main website. When a user visits the site, they can choose which course to take and click on a "Register" link to be taken to the externally hosted form.

I was able to get the GA tags changed on the framed pages, so that step is done.

However, I realise that in order to properly cross-domain track with Google Analytics, I need to also add an onclick event to any links that bring users to those pages, such as the example below.

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page1.html" onClick="pageTracker._link('http://www.mysite.com/page1.html'); return false;"> Link </a>
```

However, the site I'm working with is in Wordpress, and when I view the link in there it looks like this:

```
[iab_event link="http://www.EXAMPLESITE.com/course/4105/register.asp" text="Register"]
```

And when you view the page source of the live site this link is translated to this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadevent('http://www.EXAMPLESITE.com/course/4105/register.asp');">Register</a>
```

I tried adding the second onclick event to the one above, but that didn't work. Is there any way to add the **onClick="pageTracker._link('http://www.EXAMPLESITE.com/course/4105/register.asp'); return false;"** to this link without breaking it?

Thank you in advance for any advice given!

Comment: Wordpress will strip out javascript from your code by default. You probably need an extension to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try stacking them in the `onclick` event like this:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadevent('http://www.EXAMPLESITE.com/course/4105/register.asp');pageTracker._link('http://www.EXAMPLESITE.com/course/4105/register.asp'); return false;">Register</a>
```

It should run all of the commands as long as they're separated by semi-colons.